# Jenkins groovy global lib declarative pipeline error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

My jenkins file has below two line

```
@Library(['global-jenkins-lib@master']) _
driBuildPipeline {}
```

It is calling "driBuildPipeline.groovy" under VAR dir of global-jenkins-lib.

my script is a below:

```
def call(body) {
    def pipelineParams = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()
    println("Starting Pipeline....")
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            label 'DRIOrchestrationBuild'
            yamlFile 'build-pod.yaml'
        }
    }
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5', daysToKeepStr: '10'))
        timestamps()
    }
    environment {
        gsm = 'Name'
    }
    stages {
        stage('DRI Orchestration Build Preparation') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    echo 'Prepering.........' /
                    ls -l
                    """
            }
        }
        stage('DRI Orchestration Build Start') {
            steps {
                sh "echo DRI Orchestration Build Started...."
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

but while I am running my build I am getting below error log.

```
refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 3e8279cf8426831010fc5a0b0394201fde4b1790 (master)
git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
git checkout -f 3e8279cf8426831010fc5a0b0394201fde4b1790 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update driBuildPipeline.groovy"
git rev-list --no-walk 8d87b4f16d320639cc27fcbe6221fa5b6cbe065a # timeout=10
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
at driBuildPipeline.call(driBuildPipeline.groovy:5)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:2)
at cps.transform (Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor326.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Finished: FAILURE

Is this any kind of bug or I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Your global var method expects an argument of type `Closure` and you are passing nothing to the method as an argument; ergo `Cannot invoke method call() on null object`. If you do not need an argument, then you should remove it from the method definition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object` but I do know you need to add shared library in `Manage jenkins` - `Configure system` - `Global Pipeline Libraries`